# How to pass variable to Component received in props?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

In Layout.jsx I´ve the following structure, where children is a Component.

How can I pass 'name' to 'children' component?

```
const Home = () => {
    return <h1>Hello world!</h1>; {/* here I need the name */}
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Layout>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
                ...
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
        );
    }
}

class Layout extends Component {
    name = "John";
    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        return (
        <div>
            { children }
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

React component has to be uppercase. If the `child` variable holds a React component, you can just store it inside some uppercase variable and then render as a tag.

```
const { child: Child } = this.props;

return (
  <div>
    <Child name={this.name} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! 
Tried your solution but got the following error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: @Dane411 That probably means that `child` is not a React Component. Please console.log it and put in your post

Comment: Layout.jsx:100 {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}

Comment: @Dane411 Seems like its a correct React component. Try `const Child = this.props.child` and then render it `<Child />`. Im like 100% sure that it should work properly.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I've updated the code in case I was omitting something necessary

Comment: @Dane411 But now I can see you are not passing that `child` prop anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184587/discussion-between-dane411-and-kind-user).

Answer (score 0):

Try const { children: Child } = this.props;